# Display alert or msgbox after successfully submission

Tags: javascript, php

Haii,

I like to display some msg or alert that say "Thank for submit" after user submit the form. How to do that? Where are the perfect location to put msg/alert code on my code?Here my insert data to mysql code.

```html
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE `admin` SET user_name=%s, password=%s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['pass1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "double"));

  mysql_select_db($database_pspm, $pspm);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $pspm) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "adminupdate.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}
```

I try this code before, but not working.

```js
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: you are redirecting after update

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line  header(...),replacing it with is code:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent");';
echo 'window.location="'.$updateGoTo.'";';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rain. Your code working on the fly! 
I appreciate your kindness

Answer (score 0):

Please put the javascript code before this code :-

```
echo '<script>alert("Thanku for submit");</script>';
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
```

Or another method

```
echo '<script>alert("Thanku for submit");window.location="your path where you want to redirect";</script>';
```